# How many $4$-digit strings can be formed if each digit is either a $9$ or $0$?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a $4$ digit number each one is either a $9$ or $0$ how many different combinations is there as an example $0000, 0009 , 0090, 0900, 9000$ are all different combinations.

I know the answer is $16$ but what is the formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you are asking for is

$k^n$ where $k$ is the number of possible values for each single digit(here $k=2$ since the only values acceptable for each digit are $0$ an $9$) and $n$ the number of digits you have(here $n=4$).

The formula can be proved with induction.